# Detect and remove successive events (rows in time series) without change in the values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have to detect a faulty sensors in 10 years of time series with time step of 5 minutes. The code should be the fastest possible.

*For example:*

```
 time<-seq(from=as.POSIXct("2009-01-09 00:00"),to=as.POSIXct("2009-01-09 01:35"), by= "5 min")

  A<-c(4.325775,5.11995,6.845995,5.56784, 1.845995,1.845995,1.845995,1.845995,9.45555,9.45558,
 5.93295,8.28395,9.645665,3.79955,6.34233,2.545995,1.745335,4.33321,9.125948,5.645568)


  df<-data.frame(time,A)
  df

   time                A
1  2009-01-09 00:00:00 4.325775
2  2009-01-09 00:05:00 5.119950
3  2009-01-09 00:10:00 6.845995
4  2009-01-09 00:15:00 5.567840
5  2009-01-09 00:20:00 1.845995
6  2009-01-09 00:25:00 1.845995
7  2009-01-09 00:30:00 1.845995
8  2009-01-09 00:35:00 1.845995
9  2009-01-09 00:40:00 9.455550
10 2009-01-09 00:45:00 9.455580
11 2009-01-09 00:50:00 5.932950
12 2009-01-09 00:55:00 8.283950
13 2009-01-09 01:00:00 9.645665
14 2009-01-09 01:05:00 3.799550
15 2009-01-09 01:10:00 6.342330
16 2009-01-09 01:15:00 2.545995
17 2009-01-09 01:20:00 1.745335
18 2009-01-09 01:25:00 4.333210
19 2009-01-09 01:30:00 9.125948
20 2009-01-09 01:35:00 5.645568
```

Now I want to delete the rows where between sucessive events there is no change, for example the rows `5,6,7,8` should be deleted. If the change is really small (smaller than 0.001) then it should be deleted as well (rows `9 and 10`).

I was trying to use rle but dont know if it is possible to identify and delete the row/s where there is no change or the change is small enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove *"duplicates"* <sup>based on three digits of A</sup> :

```
#Assuming df is already ordered based on time column
#Get the A values with three digits (0.000)
#Remove the rows which round(A,3) is the same for them
df[!(duplicated(round(df$A,3)) | duplicated(round(df$A,3), fromLast = TRUE)), ]

##                   time        A
## 1  2009-01-09 00:00:00 4.325775
## 2  2009-01-09 00:05:00 5.119950
## 3  2009-01-09 00:10:00 6.845995
## 4  2009-01-09 00:15:00 5.567840
## 11 2009-01-09 00:50:00 5.932950
## 12 2009-01-09 00:55:00 8.283950
## 13 2009-01-09 01:00:00 9.645665
## 14 2009-01-09 01:05:00 3.799550
## 15 2009-01-09 01:10:00 6.342330
## 16 2009-01-09 01:15:00 2.545995
## 17 2009-01-09 01:20:00 1.745335
## 18 2009-01-09 01:25:00 4.333210
## 19 2009-01-09 01:30:00 9.125948
## 20 2009-01-09 01:35:00 5.645568
```

Benchmarking the solutions:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    Dplyr  = df %>% 
                  mutate(n_minus_1 = lag(A), 
                  change = A - n_minus_1) %>% 
                  filter(change > 0.000) %>%
                  select(-n_minus_1),
    Base_R = df[!(duplicated(round(df$A,3)) | duplicated(round(df$A,3), fromLast = TRUE)), ])


## Unit: microseconds
##    expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
##   Dplyr 16400.436 16775.964 17334.0477 17006.7475 17501.9980 20525.279   100
##  Base_R   203.259   207.494   227.6161   224.8175   241.5635   396.509   100
```

Comment: The both approaches are working just fine, but I should have the information on the date and time.

Comment: @kelamahim I thought you want the fastest one. Look at the benchmark. `dplyr` is 80 times slower.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution in dplyr :

```
df %>% 
  mutate(n_minus_1 = lag(A), 
         change = A - n_minus_1) %>% 
  filter(change > 0.000)


                 time        A n_minus_1   change
1 2009-01-09 00:05:00 5.119950  4.325775 0.794175
2 2009-01-09 00:10:00 6.845995  5.119950 1.726045
3 2009-01-09 00:40:00 9.455550  1.845995 7.609555
4 2009-01-09 00:45:00 9.455580  9.455550 0.000030
5 2009-01-09 00:55:00 8.283950  5.932950 2.351000
6 2009-01-09 01:00:00 9.645665  8.283950 1.361715
7 2009-01-09 01:10:00 6.342330  3.799550 2.542780
8 2009-01-09 01:25:00 4.333210  1.745335 2.587875
9 2009-01-09 01:30:00 9.125948  4.333210 4.792738
```

You can of course remove the `n_minus_1` col :

```
df %>% 
  mutate(n_minus_1 = lag(A), 
         change = A - n_minus_1) %>% 
  filter(change > 0.000) %>%
  select(-n_minus_1)

                 time        A   change
1 2009-01-09 00:05:00 5.119950 0.794175
2 2009-01-09 00:10:00 6.845995 1.726045
3 2009-01-09 00:40:00 9.455550 7.609555
4 2009-01-09 00:45:00 9.455580 0.000030
5 2009-01-09 00:55:00 8.283950 2.351000
6 2009-01-09 01:00:00 9.645665 1.361715
7 2009-01-09 01:10:00 6.342330 2.542780
8 2009-01-09 01:25:00 4.333210 2.587875
9 2009-01-09 01:30:00 9.125948 4.792738
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to keep the first row of a sequence of successive duplicate rows, here is a solution using dplyr based on the answer of Colin FAY which is corrected and simplified:

```
df |> 
  dplyr::arrange(time) |> 
  dplyr::filter(abs(A - dplyr::lag(A, default = -Inf)) > 0.001)
# time        A
# 1  2009-01-09 00:00:00 4.325775
# 2  2009-01-09 00:05:00 5.119950
# 3  2009-01-09 00:10:00 6.845995
# 4  2009-01-09 00:15:00 5.567840
# 5  2009-01-09 00:20:00 1.845995
# 6  2009-01-09 00:40:00 9.455550
# 7  2009-01-09 00:50:00 5.932950
# 8  2009-01-09 00:55:00 8.283950
# 9  2009-01-09 01:00:00 9.645665
# 10 2009-01-09 01:05:00 3.799550
# 11 2009-01-09 01:10:00 6.342330
# 12 2009-01-09 01:15:00 2.545995
# 13 2009-01-09 01:20:00 1.745335
# 14 2009-01-09 01:25:00 4.333210
# 15 2009-01-09 01:30:00 9.125948
# 16 2009-01-09 01:35:00 5.645568
```

Note that is keeps the first row of successive duplicate rows. If you wish to keep the last row instead, use dplyr::lead() instead of dplyr::lag().

If the df is sorted by time already you can skip  dplyr::arrange().

The problem with the previous solution is that it keeps only rows where the value of A increases from one row to the next but actually it might decrease or increase. We need to sort out rows where the absolute value of the change in A is larger than 0.
Also note that we need to set a default value for the dplyr::lag() function, otherwise incorrectly remove the first row.

Only removing duplicate values of A does not help because it removes all duplicates and not only duplicates of successive rows (events).